# Concavity and inflection points for $x|x-1|$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

**Problem**

Find where the function $f(x) = x|x-1|$ is convex and concave, and find any points of inflection.

**My progress**

I've found $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ (see below), the latter taking ages, but I'm having a hard time solving $f''(x) = 0$ to find the inflection points, and also evaluating $f''(x) > 0$ and the opposite, to find the concavity.

**Question**

Is there a better way to do this? The expressions are killing me!

**Side notes**

This is an exam problem, given in 2014. It seems odd that this should be the only way of solving it.

What I have found is $$f'(x) = |x-1| + \frac{x(x-1)}{|x-1|}$$

$$f''(x) = \frac{x-1}{|x-1|} + \frac{(x-1)^3}{|x-1|^3}$$

but like I mentioned, I'm finding the latter hard to work with.

Comment: $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x(x-1), & x\ge 1 \\ x(1-x), & x\lt 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Damn. I'm such an idiot. Of course I should be working with the piecewise definition instead! Thanks, @Bye_World!

Comment: @Bye_World You meant $x\leqslant 1$ and $x\geqslant 1$.

Comment: @Alec No problem.

Comment: @Alec Remember that's is usually a bad idea to compute a derivative of a function written with absolute values, as the absolute value function itself is not differentiable at $0$.